# Refresh Fragment From Activity After Updating Data on SQLite Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I got an issue with my Android program when updating user data on **Fragment_profile**. Fragment_Profile loads User profile data and contains an update button in which the button navigates to an activity called **EditProfileActivity**. Users can technically update the data but, after they save the updated data, the data still can't be updated. The old data still appear. I try to refresh the fragment by using OnResume() and add OnRestart on my EditProfileActivity.cs and OnPause both in fragment and activity but, still nothing. I am using Xamarin Android and develop it with C#. For more info, you can see what happened in the GIF
[My issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4WmI.png)

So far, I've tried to code, and here's my code. 
**Fragment_profile.cs**

```
public class Fragment_Profile : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public HomePageActivity m_currentActivity;

        public TextView m_tv_loginname, m_tv_username, m_tv_fullname , m_tv_dob;

        public Boolean isRefreshing = false;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle aSavedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(aSavedInstanceState);
        }

        //public static Fragment_Profile NewInstance(Model.User aCurrentUser)
        public static Fragment_Profile NewInstance()
        {
            var _frag4 = new Fragment_Profile { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return _frag4;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater aInflater, ViewGroup aContainer, Bundle aSavedInstanceState)
        {
            var _ignored = base.OnCreateView(aInflater, aContainer, aSavedInstanceState);
            var view= aInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentProfile, null);

            m_tv_loginname = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_loginname);
            m_tv_username = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_userEmail);
            m_tv_fullname = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_fullname);
            m_tv_dob = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_dob);


            Button _updateProfile = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnUpdateProfile);

            _updateProfile.Click += _updateProfile_Click;

            m_currentActivity = (HomePageActivity)this.Activity;

            if (m_currentActivity.CurrentUser != null)
            {
                //string  = "Welcome, " + m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.UserName;
                m_tv_loginname.Text = m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.LoginName;
                m_tv_fullname.Text = m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.UserName;
                m_tv_username.Text = m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.UserEmail;
                m_tv_dob.Text = m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.DateOfBirth;
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "The data is not found!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(i);
                this.Activity.Finish();
            }


            return view;
        }

        private void _updateProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Context, typeof(EditProfileActivity));
            i.PutExtra("loginname", m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.LoginName);
            i.PutExtra("fullname", m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.UserName);
            i.PutExtra("useremail", m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.UserEmail);
            i.PutExtra("dob", m_currentActivity.CurrentUser.DateOfBirth);
            StartActivity(i);
        }

        public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            if (isRefreshing)
            {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment_Profile();
                Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentMg = Activity.SupportFragmentManager;
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTrans = fragmentMg.BeginTransaction();
                fragmentTrans.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);
                fragmentTrans.Detach(fragment);
                fragmentTrans.Attach(fragment);
                fragmentTrans.Commit();

                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        public override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
                isRefreshing = true;
        }
    }
```

When user click the `_updateProfile button` It will reference to next activity which is EditProfileActivity. Here's my **EditProfileActivity.cs**

```
 public class EditProfileActivity : Activity, IOnDateSetListener
    {
        public EditText m_editFullName, m_editUsername, m_dob;
        public TextView m_tvEmail;
        public Button m_btnUpdate;
        public Boolean isRefreshing = false;



        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EditProfile);

            m_editFullName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_editfullName);
             m_editUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_editUserName);
            m_tvEmail = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_Email);
             m_dob = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.et_editDob);
            m_btnUpdate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_updateprofile);

            m_btnUpdate.Click += _btnUpdate_Click;

            m_dob.Click += _dob_Click;

            Bundle extras = Intent.Extras;
            m_editFullName.Text = extras.GetString("loginname");
            m_editUsername.Text = extras.GetString("fullname");
            m_tvEmail.Text = extras.GetString("useremail");
            m_dob.Text = extras.GetString("dob");


        }

        private void _btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Model.User _currentUser = Model.User.CheckEmailUser(m_tvEmail.Text);
                _currentUser.UserName = m_editUsername.Text;
                _currentUser.LoginName = m_editFullName.Text;
                _currentUser.UserEmail = m_tvEmail.Text;
                _currentUser.DateOfBirth = m_dob.Text;

               var _updated =  DBManager.Instance.Update(_currentUser);

                if (_updated > 0)
                {

                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Your account has been succesfully updated!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    Finish();
                    OnResume();
                }

                else
                {
                       Toast.MakeText(this, "Failed to update!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }

            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }

        private void _dob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
            DatePickerDialog _datepicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, this
                , _dateTimeNow.Year, _dateTimeNow.Month, _dateTimeNow.Day);
            _datepicker.Show();
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            m_dob.Text = new DateTime(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth).ToShortDateString();
        }

        protected override void OnRestart()
        {
            base.OnRestart();
            if (isRefreshing)
            {
                isRefreshing = false;
                Finish();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            if (!isRefreshing)
                isRefreshing = true;
        }


    }
```

I also have read some articles that have the same problems as me but, It still confusing me and still same. I know it's a simple thing but, It took a few days for me because I am a newby and I still don't get the solution. 
Do you guys have any ideas? Would you like to help me? If you don't mind please check my source code so, I know what I am missing. Thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you Fragment, you can override the `OnResume` method. If you back to the fragment from Acitivty. you should query the new data from DB, then set the new value to the controls in Fragment.

```
 public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            PHName.Text = photoDAO.GetFirstPhotos(Id).PhotoName;
        }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

You can see this lifecycle about Fragment. Every time you display the Fragment,`OnResume` method will be executed. You get the newest data from DB, then set it to the `Fragment` page.
[image]

Here is my demo.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11dROKS7TtqAaVYkG8w6ZKpqnQJRBD87E/view

Comment: Wow! It's like magic! THANK YOU! IT WORKS! You are a kind person! I accept your answer! and thank you for your explanation. It helps me a lot!